# Oracle JSON Text Search on Nested Objects to unknown depth?

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I'm storing data similar to the following in an Oracle 12c database:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "el": "p",
         "attributes": {
             "class": "abc"
         },
         "children": [
            {
               "el": "strong",
               "children": []
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see this could be nested to any level. However I need to perform a query to see which objects have a class attribute of `x`. I've tried many of the Oracle JSON functions, however they all seem to work with fixed paths or arrays with a known depth.

Is there any way to run a query on the JSON without knowing the depth of the objects?

Comment: The Json you've posted is not a valid Json. Use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) link to validate json and correct the errors and post the correct one. I'm sure no one here has the time to spend to correct it for you.

Comment: I agree with @KaushikNayak. Having this data as not stored in a json column, you may refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56802155/5841306) as being a user of Oracle12c.

Comment: I have updated the JSON @KaushikNayak. However this was just an example and not the actual data stored in the DB. We have Oracle check constraints for the JSON columns to verify valid JSON.